# How to get the String Value to the textbox using javascript with asp.net

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, string, textbox

I am creating a folder by generating a random string and I need to get that string value to the textbox using javascript.

Here is my javascript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var tempDir = randomString(8);
                document.getElementById("currentDirectory").value = tempDir;
                alert(tempDir);
</script>
```

This is the textbox where I need to display

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: My answer worked for you now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by simply declaring the control this way inside the body tag.

```
('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>')
```

Comment: I don't think my answer is indifferent then the one you posted. You should have considered accepting my answer but alas choice is yours. :(

Answer (score 2):

That's It,

```
document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID  %>').value = tempdir;
```

In asp.net the id of elements changes when rendered in browser so you need to take the.Id from control's ClientID property.

Comment: Sorry Harsh it's not working as It's showing me error at the control ID property.So I am trying to make it work.

Comment: So you can update the question with new implementation of your javascript code and the control syntax. It would be more clear then.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try JQuery

```
 $("#ControlID").val(tempDir);
```

You'll want to check how the control is rendered in the HTML though since it's an ASP.Net control.  Sometimes the ID changes a bit and you'll want the command to use that in place of ControlID above.